# Making a model retrieve external JSON feed with Alloy in Titanium

Tags: json, collections, model, external, appcelerator-mobile

I've searched the net through for examples and tutorials on using the Alloy framework for Titanium to fetch data from an external JSON feed.

What I need to do is simply to collect strings and images from a JSON feed and display them in a TableView.

If I understand the structure of Alloy and Backbone correctly, what I need to do is to setup a model that retrieves the data from the JSON feed, ex: http://www.domain.com/api.php?function=getproducts

And a collection to populate the application TableView.

I'm not very much into Backbone, I've read the introduction and looked in the documentation, but I don't really get enough of it to make this solution on my own. Hope for some directions to Alloy oriented examples with similar solutions as I need or a nice soul that would help me figure this out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reading through it, I guess what I need to do is to create the database in the model and sync it with the JSON feed?

Comment: If anyone comes across this post, I figured you have to make a custom adapter to do this. Happy coding!